# Entity Framework/ table relationships

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I have a table in which all the fields are registered, for example, in my table "Id_Cus" is the primary key. How to correctly indicate that in the 2 table "Id_Cus" was taken from 1 table? I attach screenshots

I attached classes where field properties are registered. However, in the first table, the implementation of these fields is embedded in the interface. Tell me where exactly should I indicate that the "Id_Cus" in the second table should be taken from the first table (in the class itself, as in the screenshot or in the interface) and how to do it?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using MySql.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;

using WcfRestFullService.Model;

namespace WcfRestFullService
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "CustomerSevice" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select CustomerSevice.svc or CustomerSevice.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class CustomerSevice : ICustomerSevice
    {
        MySQLEntities dc;
        public CustomerSevice()
        {
            dc = new MySQLEntities();
        }

        public List<customer> GetAllCustomer()
        {
            var query = (from a in dc.customers
                         select a).Distinct().Include(c=>c.customerpreference);

            List<customer> CustomersList = new List<customer>();

            query.ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                CustomersList.Add(new customer
                {
                    Id_Cus = x.Id_Cus,
                    FirstName_Cus = x.FirstName_Cus,
                    LastName_Cus = x.LastName_Cus,
                    PhoneNum_Cus = x.PhoneNum_Cus,
                    Email_Cus = x.Email_Cus,
                });
            });
            return CustomersList;
        }

        public customer CustomerDetails(string Id_Cus)
        {
            customer Cust = new customer();
            try
            {
                var query = (from a in dc.customers
                             where a.Id_Cus.Equals(Id_Cus)
                             select a).Distinct().FirstOrDefault();
                Cust.Id_Cus = query.Id_Cus;
                Cust.FirstName_Cus = query.FirstName_Cus;
                Cust.LastName_Cus = query.LastName_Cus;
                Cust.PhoneNum_Cus = query.PhoneNum_Cus;
                Cust.Email_Cus = query.Email_Cus;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new FaultException<string>(ex.Message);
            }
            return Cust;
        }

        // DELETE

        public void DeleteCustomer(string Id_Cus)
        {
            //MySQLEntities Cust = new MySQLEntities(); //check the file Model.edmx->ModelContext.tt->MySQLEntitys

            int k = Convert.ToInt32(Id_Cus);
            customer cur = (from n in dc.customers
                            where n.Id_Cus == k
                            select n).ToList().First();

            dc.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            dc.customers.Remove(cur);
            dc.SaveChanges();
        }

        //Insert/POST

        public void InsertCustomer(customer customerDataContract)
        {
            //MySQLEntities Cust = new MySQLEntities();
            customer cust = new customer();

            cust.Id_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.Id_Cus);
            cust.FirstName_Cus = customerDataContract.FirstName_Cus;
            cust.LastName_Cus = customerDataContract.LastName_Cus;
            cust.PhoneNum_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.PhoneNum_Cus);
            cust.Email_Cus = customerDataContract.Email_Cus;
            dc.customers.Add(cust);
            dc.SaveChanges();
        }

        //Update/PUT
        public void UpdateCustomer(customer customerDataContract)
        {
            //using (CustomerDataContract Cust = new CustomerDataContract())
            //using (MySQLEntities Cust = new MySQLEntities()) 
            {
                int k = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.Id_Cus);
                customer cust = dc.customers.Where(n => n.Id_Cus == k).Include(a=>a.customerpreference).FirstOrDefault();

                cust.Id_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.Id_Cus);
                cust.FirstName_Cus = customerDataContract.FirstName_Cus;
                cust.LastName_Cus = customerDataContract.LastName_Cus;
                cust.PhoneNum_Cus = Convert.ToInt32(customerDataContract.PhoneNum_Cus);
                cust.Email_Cus = customerDataContract.Email_Cus;

                dc.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WcfRestFullService.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Web;

    [DataContract]
    public partial class customerpreference
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int Id_Cus { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Id_Res { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name_Dis { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Id_Type { get; set; }

        public virtual customer customer { get; set; }
        public virtual order order { get; set; }
        public virtual type_dishes type_dishes { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated from a template.
//
//     Manual changes to this file may cause unexpected behavior in your application.
//     Manual changes to this file will be overwritten if the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace WcfRestFullService.Model
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;
    using System.Web;

    [DataContract]
    public partial class customer
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public customer()
        {
            this.dishesrankings = new HashSet<dishesranking>();
            this.orders = new HashSet<order>();
        }

        [DataMember]
        public int Id_Cus { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string FirstName_Cus { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string LastName_Cus { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int PhoneNum_Cus { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Email_Cus { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<dishesranking> dishesrankings { get; set; }
        public virtual customerpreference customerpreference { get; set; }
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<order> orders { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inOKi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jS97.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0RMb.png)

Comment: It would help us if you gave us the classes that represent your tables and the relations between the tables. This will also give us an impression of what you tried.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I added

Answer (score 0):

The Property of your foreign key in table  should be

```
Public ICollection<CustomerDataContract> IdCus {get;set;}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried, but the second table is displayed completely empty (Without Id_Cus), maybe there is a problem in the settings of web.config?
I will attach a screenshot, maybe you could tell if everything is correct there, besides this I changed the screenshot according to your recommendation, right?